# Fingerprint AuthenticationCallback in LoginActivity

Tags: java, android, class

How can I call the method "loginprep" of the LoginActivityClass from the FingerPrintClass?

See in the code...I wrote in where I want to call the loginprep with: "//Here I need the method loginprep() from the LoginActivity class"

**FingerprintHandler.java**

```
public class FingerprintHandler extends FingerprintManager.AuthenticationCallback {

private Context context;

// Constructor
public FingerprintHandler(Context mContext) {
    context = mContext;
}

public void startAuth(FingerprintManager manager, FingerprintManager.CryptoObject cryptoObject) {
    CancellationSignal cancellationSignal = new CancellationSignal();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    manager.authenticate(cryptoObject, cancellationSignal, 0, this, null);
}

@Override
public void onAuthenticationError(int errMsgId, CharSequence errString) {
    Toast.makeText((Activity)context, "Fingerprint Authentication error.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onAuthenticationHelp(int helpMsgId, CharSequence helpString) {
    Toast.makeText((Activity)context, "Fingerprint Authentication help.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onAuthenticationFailed() {
    Toast.makeText((Activity)context, "Fingerprint Authentication failed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(FingerprintManager.AuthenticationResult result) {



    //Here I need the method loginprep() from the LoginActivity class




  }
}
```

**LoginActivity.java**

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void loginprep() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesF = getSharedPreferences("loginDatasFinger", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String urn = sharedPreferencesF.getString("username", "");
        String pwd =  sharedPreferencesF.getString("password", "");
        loginUser(urn, pwd);
    }

    private void launchHomeScreen() {
        Intent homeActivity = new Intent (LoginActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
        LoginActivity.this.startActivity(homeActivity);
        finish();
    }

    public void loginUser(final String urn, final String pwd){
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(LoginActivity.this, "", "Loading...");
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            System.out.println("JSON RESPONSE: " + jsonResponse.toString());
                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                            if (success) {
                                launchHomeScreen();
                                pd.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Welcome back " + urn,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("loginDatas", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                                editor.putString("username", urn);
                                editor.putString("password", pwd);
                                editor.apply();
                            }
                            else {
                                loginButton.setBackgroundColor(0x73000000);
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Wrong Username or Password!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                pd.dismiss();
                            }
                        }
                        catch (JSONException e) {
                            loginButton.setBackgroundColor(0x73000000);
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            pd.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        loginButton.setBackgroundColor(0x73000000);
                        pd.dismiss();
                        System.out.println("Error: " + error);
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put(KEY_USERNAME,urn);
                params.put(KEY_PASSWORD,pwd);
                return params;
            }

        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not create an instance of activity class. that's wrong. You only declare activity in manifest.  You need to provide more info on what code you have in another class.

Comment: It is obviously connected with Android's basics like activity lifecycle...

Comment: @BAAAZINGA What do you mean?

Comment: This question has been answering over and over again, but I cant find a reasonable duplicate... Please show what you're trying to do in `update`... You realize that calling "update" on a `new` *anything*, doesn't make sense, right? There's no views to update in an Activity if they weren't setup in `onCreate`

Comment: *User gets message* is too vague... Communication between Activities is only possible with Intents or persistent data. Between other application's component we have more choices... Like BroadcastReceivers or service's binding.

Comment: [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of the app, please

Comment: @cricket_007 Ok now? :)

Comment: Not exactly. You're missing `loginUser`. Please see link again about being "complete"

Comment: @cricket_007 Can, you please read my post again. I updated it with more details... :)

Comment: I can't really tell how to you are using `FingerprintHandler`. Can you add that  code?

Answer (score 1):

Following:

```
 MainActivity mActivity = new MainActivity();
```

this is not the way Android is expecting you to create new instances of an activity, normally you wait the onCreate callback as described in the activity lifeCycle...
[image]

no following that approach you will need another way to communicate 2 different activities, what way must be taken depends on the specific arch of your application... the most commonly implemented could be using self defined interfaces and implement you custom callbacks...

Answer (score 1):

You're writing a FingerPrint **callback** class, which means there is some `onAuthenticationSucceeded` method that is called when the "authentication succeeds."

How about you implement your own callback to pass back into the `LoginActivity`?

In other words, you'd

**1)** Write an interface

```
public interface LoginListener {
    void onLoginSuccess();
    void onLoginFailed();
}
```

**2)** Have the Activity `implements LoginListener` and have the Activity method of `onLogin` do your non-static stuff with the SharedPreferences,

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
    implements LoginListener {

    public static final String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
    public static final String KEY_PASS = "password"; 

    private FingerprintHandler fingerprintHandler;

    @Override
    public void onLoginFailed() { } 

    @Override
    public void onLoginSuccess() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("loginDatasFinger", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String urn = sharedPrefs.getString(KEY_USERNAME, "");
        String pwd =  sharedPrefs.getString(KEY_PASS, "");
        loginUser(urn, pwd);
    }

    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        super.onCreate(b);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        fingerprintHandler = new FingerprintHandler(this); 
    }

    // public void loginUser(final String urn, final String pwd){ }

}
```

**3)**  Expect to pass in a `LoginListener` as a parameter to that separate class.

```
public class FingerprintHandler extends FingerprintManager.AuthenticationCallback {

    private final Context mContext;
    private LoginListener mListener;

    // Constructor
    public FingerprintHandler(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        if (context instanceof LoginListener) {
            this.mListener = (LoginListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new ClassCastException("FingerprintHandler: context must implement LoginListener!");
        }
    }
```

**4)** And you do then can use your callback from the other callback.

```
@Override
public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(FingerprintManager.AuthenticationResult result) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onLoginSuccess();
    }
}
```

Comment: but i don't wanna have a static one

Comment: I only said that a method involving SharedPrefences  could be static, not that you are required to have one... Just ignore that statement and the rest of the answer never mentioned static

Comment: But how to fix my problem?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what problem you have. I've tried to explain one solution. I'm sorry you don't understand it

Comment: @user7118518 Please check if my edits make sense now

Comment: Can you please look at my LoginActivity.java...I added: It's extends AppCompatActivity....What couldI use now... :)

Comment: There is no difference between `Activity` and `AppCompatActivity` in my answer

Comment: The weired thing is that I get the Erros from Activitys, which hasn't to do anything with this part..Errors like: `Error:(229, 38) error: no suitable method found for makeText(RegisterActivity,String,int)
method Toast.makeText(Context,CharSequence,int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; RegisterActivity cannot be converted to Context)
method Toast.makeText(Context,int,int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; RegisterActivity cannot be converted to Context)`

Comment: Seems unrelated to my answer. Feel free to create a new post